# fullcalendar how to add div only in month view

Tags: jquery, css, fullcalendar

I want to add custom div in event's fc-content ONLY in month view

JS

```
 eventRender: function(event, eventElement) {                            
                   eventElement.find('div.fc-content').
    append('<div class="circle"></div>');                           
            }
```

code above adds class circle in all views. I tried

```
find('div.fc-month-view div.fc-content')
```

with no success. Any suggestion?

Comment: Any Fiddle, CodePen, or demo will be helpful.

Comment: You can use the method [`getView`](https://fullcalendar.io/docs1/views/getView/) and check if its `month` append the `div`, if not, remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_rendering/eventRender/, the eventRender callback provides you with a third parameter, which you aren't using in your code. This parameter contains the current view object. You can use this to determine which view is currently being used, and therefore whether to append your extra content or not:

```
eventRender: function( event, element, view ) {
    if (view.name == "month")
    {
        element.find('div.fc-content').append('<div class="circle"></div>'); 
    }
},
```

See here for a working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/sbxpv25p/78/